# How to interpret a statement consisting of two ORs?

Tags: meaning, conjunctions

I found this statement on a newspaper that is the subject of a recent controversy:

> "no guarantee or loan shall be given or raised by the Government
>   except under the authority of any resolution of Parliament with which
>   the President concurs"

There are two possible interpretations:

> "(no guarantee shall be given) or (no loan shall be raised) by the
>   Government except under the authority of any resolution of Parliament
>   with which the President concurs"

OR

> (no guarantee or loan) shall be (given or raised) by the Government
>   except under the authority of any resolution of Parliament with which
>   the President concurs"

I am confused. Which should be the correct interpretation. I am looking for answers that provide references, not personal opinions. Thanks.

Comment: I'm just going to say that--(imo)--your second way of interpretation seems like the correct way. (It was what I originally thought when I read the first part _before_ seeing your interpretations.)

Comment: Yes, your second option is correct- the ORs merely are used to rephrase or restate the intention of the author or his agency.

Answer (score 3):

Since “guarantees” are not ordinarily “raised” (except in cases where they are increased) and “loans” are not “given” (if you “give” it, it's not a loan) your first interpretation is closest.  What the draftsman almost certainly **means** is:

> No guarantee shall be given by the Government except under the authority of any resolution of Parliament with which the President concurs,
>   AND
>   no loan shall be raised by the Government except under the authority of any resolution of Parliament with which the President concurs.

(Note, by the way, that “any” here is a mistake for “some”, and it really wants a few more words.)

But he doesn't want to repeat that long string “by the ... concurs”; so he tries to fudge his way through by using the “No X or Y” construction; and he ends up with an awkward sentence which **says** what your second interpretation admirably describes.

It probably doesn't much matter; but it's slovenly.

I'm afraid I can't give you any references—I never owned the manuals I worked with—but thirty years ago I spent three years drafting pleadings and working with my principal, an arbitrator, to figure out just how to interpret bad legal drafting in order to reach a decision; so I know a little bit about it.

Comment: +1 Not only the interpretation is correct, it's not even necessary to go to that length. It is a commonly used structure in formal writing, esp., legalese, to use "respective" grouping as this. The order in which the first list appears applies one-to-one in the succeeding list(s).

Comment: Hmm, you are addressing this from an entirely different perspective. Let me see if someone can address the grouping rules that @Kris mentioned which I am also interested to find out :)

Comment: @QuestionOverflow I think I'm only looking at it from a simpler and more 'natural' perspective, that should be familiar to most regular readers.

Comment: My only issue with this answer (which I have upvoted) is the opinion that the usage in this instance is slovenly.  As @Kris mentioned, this is a structure found in diverse types of formal writing (including poetry).  I find legal/legislative documents which use these forms quite appealing.  This particular sentence isn't on a par with the declaration of Independence, but it is elegant enough.

Comment: @ltsbruce  *Elegance* is not the same thing as *clarity*. I invite you to consider the 2nd Amendment to the U.S. Constitution.